# Interview question - Partition and Sort LocalDate objects using Java 8 features

Tags: java, list, sorting, lambda, localdate

I received this test-task for job, but I was rejected based on my solution. Please, give me a hint what would be the best way to solve this task.

As I found out later, they want me to use Java 8 features.

```
/**
 * Marking will be based upon producing a readable, well engineered solution rather than factors
 * such as speed of processing or other performance-based optimizations, which are less
 * important.
 *
 *
 * The Date sorter interface, implement the single method
 * within this interface.
 */
public interface IDateSorter {
    /**
     * The implementation of this method should sort dates.
     * The output should be in the following order:
     * Dates with an 'r' in the month,
     * sorted ascending (first to last),
     * then dates without an 'r' in the month,
     * sorted descending (last to first).
     * For example, October dates would come before May dates,
     * because October has an 'r' in it.
     * thus: (2005-07-01, 2005-01-02, 2005-01-01, 2005-05-03)
     * would sort to
     * (2005-01-01, 2005-01-02, 2005-07-01, 2005-05-03)
     *
     * @param unsortedDates - an unsorted list of dates
     * @return the collection of dates now sorted as per the spec
     */
    Collection<LocalDate> sortDates(List<LocalDate> unsortedDates);
}
```

This was my solution.

```
@Override
public  Collection<LocalDate> sortDates(List<LocalDate> unsortedDates) {
    List<LocalDate> listWithR = new ArrayList<>();
    List<LocalDate> listWithOutR = new ArrayList<>();

    //Separate unsortedDates in to list depends on 'R' factor
    for (LocalDate date: unsortedDates) {
        if (date.getMonth().getValue() < 5 || date.getMonth().getValue() > 8) {
            listWithR.add(date);
        } else {
            listWithOutR.add(date);
        }
    }
    //Sort list with R
    Collections.sort(listWithR);

    //Sort list without R
    listWithOutR.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

    //Adding list without R to list with R
    listWithR.addAll(listWithOutR);

    return listWithR;

}
```

Comment: This looks perfectly reasonable to me.  Did they say your solution was _wrong_, or just that they wanted something that used fancier Java 8 features?

Comment: *they want me to use Java 8 features* That’s a wide and vague concept. `LocalDate` is a Java 8 feature, so they can’t claim you didn’t. Wonder if they intended streams? This can be done, of course. You may, for example, create two sorted streams using the `filter` method and then combine them using `Stream.concat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given list can be sorted as required, **in one go**, without splitting it into two parts (*and using Java 8 functional programming features as required*).

## Create a Comparator with Java 8

The approach boils down to defining the appropriate `Comparator`.

For that, we can use Java 8 static methods of the `Comparator` interface like [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)).

The first part, which groups the dates based on the Month name, can be described as follows:

```
Comparator.comparing(ld -> !ld.getMonth().name().contains("R"))
```

**Reminder:** the *natural order* of `boolean` values is `false` -> `true`, for that reason condition was negated.

And we would need to check the same condition in the second part of the Comparator (*because these groups of dates should be sorted differently*), hence it makes sense to define a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html):

```
public static final Predicate<LocalDate> HAS_NO_R = ld -> !ld.getMonth().name().contains("R");
```

And the first part would be simplified to:

```
Comparator.comparing(HAS_NO_R::test)
```

To impose the required Ascending and Descending ordering, we can use [`ChronoLocalDate.toEpochDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html#toEpochDay()), returning the number of days from epoch as `long`, in conjunction with [`Comparator.thenComparingLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)).

To make the group of date with no `"R"` in the name to be sorted in Descending order, the *epoch count* was reversed by multiplying by `(-1)`.

```
thenComparingLong(ld -> HAS_NO_R.test(ld) ? (-1) * ld.toEpochDay() : ld.toEpochDay())
```

## Complete Implementation

Now let's bring all the pieces together.

`Comparator` + `Predicate`:

```
public static final Predicate<LocalDate> HAS_NO_R = ld -> !ld.getMonth().name().contains("R");
    
public final Comparator<LocalDate> BY_MONTH_R_ASC_NO_R_DESC =
    Comparator.comparing(HAS_NO_R::test)
        .thenComparingLong(ld -> HAS_NO_R.test(ld) ?
            (-1) * ld.toEpochDay() : ld.toEpochDay()
        );
```

And here's the method itself. We can make use of the Stream API to generate the sorted list:

```
public static Collection<LocalDate> sortDates(List<LocalDate> unsortedDates) {
    
    return unsortedDates.stream()         // assumption that original list should not be mutated
        .sorted(BY_MONTH_R_ASC_NO_R_DESC)
        .toList();
}
```

***Note:*** I see no clear requirement on whether that method should return a **new** `Collection`. I've made a safe assumption that the original list should not be mutated.

Just for the purpose of completeness, that's the original list can be sorted with Java 9 [`List.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)):

```
unsortedDates.sort(BY_MONTH_R_ASC_NO_R_DESC);

return unsortedDates;
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<LocalDate> dates = List.of(
        LocalDate.parse("2005-07-01"), LocalDate.parse("2005-01-02"),
        LocalDate.parse("2005-01-01"), LocalDate.parse("2005-05-03")
    );

    sortDates(dates).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
2005-01-01
2005-01-02
2005-07-01
2005-05-03
```

Comment: @Abra The name of the *enum* [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) are compliant with the ISO-8601 standard. Of course, they are in English, and of course like any name of the *enum* from the JDK they are in Upper case (as per language naming convention).

Comment: See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/bQlNeL).